# How to get scalacheck to work on class with a Seq?

Tags: scala, scalacheck

I have a case class that I am trying to test via ScalaCheck. The case class contains other classes.

Here are the classes:

```
case class Shop(name: String = "", colors: Seq[Color] = Nil)
case class Color(colorName: String = "", shades: Seq[Shade] = Nil)
case class Shade(shadeName: String, value: Int)
```

I have generators for each one

```
implicit def shopGen: Gen[Shop] = 
  for {
    name <- Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.length > 0)
    colors <- Gen.listOf(colorsGen)
  } yield Shop(name, colors)

implicit def colorsGen: Gen[Color] =
  for {
   colorName <- Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.length > 0)
   shades <- Gen.listOf(shadesGen)
  } yield Color(colorName, shades)

implicit def shadesGen: Gen[Shade] = 
  for {
    shadeName <- Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.length > 0) //**Note this**
    value <- Gen.choose(1, Int.MaxValue)
  } yield Shade(shadeName, value)
```

When I write my test and simply do the below:

```
  property("Shops must encode/decode to/from JSON") {
     "test" mustBe "test   
  }
```

I get an error and the test hangs and stops after 51 tries. The error I get is `Gave up after 1 successful property evaluation. 51 evaluations were discarded.`

If I remove `Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.length > 0)` from `shadesGen` and just replace it with `Gen.alphaStr` then it works.

**Question**

1. Why does having `Gen.alphaStr` work for `shadesGen`, however, `Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.length > 0)` does not?
2. Also when I run test multiple times (with `Gen.alphaStr`) some pass while some don't. Why is this?

Comment: What is the property you are testing? How do you test the property? When you don't show your code, we find it difficult to help you.

Comment: I can put anything there. but still it fails. I've updated the question.

Comment: "Gave up" is the clue -- it means you are discarding too many data values, likely with the `suchThat()` filter. Change to a generator that never fails.

Comment: "Change to a generator that never fails" by this do you mean `Gen.alphaStr` instead of `Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.length > 0)` ? The former works for me but when I run multiple test runs, it sometimes fails.

Comment: Does it always fail with "Gave up ..."? If so, there must be some other filtering going on.

Comment: They are quite simple three case classes with not much logic between them. I don't see what filtering could be going on or how I can debug it further.

Comment: Well, the "gave up" message indicates that filtering is still going on.

Answer (score 2):

You probably see this behavior because of the way `listOf` is implemented. Inside it is based on `buildableOf` which is in turn based on `buildableOfN` which has following comment:

> ... If the given generator fails generating a value, the
>      complete container generator will also fail.

Your data structure is essentially a list of lists so even one bad generation will curse the whole data-structure to be discarded. And obviously most of the failures happens at the bottom level. That's why removing the filter for `shadeName` helps. So to make it work you should generate more valid strings. You may change `Gen.alphaStr` to some custom-made generator based on `nonEmptyListOf` such as:

```
def nonemptyAlphaStr:Gen[String] = Gen.nonEmptyListOf(alphaChar).map(_.mkString)
```

Another simple way to work this around is to use `retryUntil` instead of `suchThat` such as in:

```
implicit def shadesGen: Gen[Shade] =
  for {
    //shadeName <- Gen.alphaStr.suchThat(_.length > 0) //**Note this**
    shadeName <- Gen.alphaStr.retryUntil(_.length > 0)
    value <- Gen.choose(1, Int.MaxValue)
  } yield Shade(shadeName, value)
```